# QGIS 3.6 on Mac: Extracting attribute value of polygon from another layer when it overlay

Tags: field-calculator, fields-attributes, overlay, intersect

I have a layer labeled "Boundaries" with a set of polygons. I have another layer with a set of points labelled "Locations". The "Boundaries" polygons have an attribute called "name_id" with the name of every polygon. I want to add a new attribute to the points in the layer "Locations", through the field calculator, that is populated by the value of the of the polygon name when the point is within the boundary of the polygon.Any idea? I tried overlay_intersects but QGIS doesn't seem to recognize.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this expression in the field calculator:

```
array_first(overlay_intersects('Boundaries',"name_id"))
```

[image]

Another option is *Join Attributes by location* which will create a new memory layer the same as the original points but with the field from the polygon layer added:
[image]

The next image shows the points layer labeled using the new field *name_id*.

Comment: What app do you use for screenshot?

Comment: I am using QGIS 3.6 on a Macintosh. It doesn't seem to recognize the function overlay_intersects(). I get a "Function not found" message.

Comment: No experience of QGIS on mac.  I have edited the original answer with another way of getting the result  you want.

Comment: Screenshots done with Snagit

Comment: I re-installed QGIS V3.30 on Mac instead of the 3.6 I had before and both your suggestions worked fine.

Comment: If the suggestions provided by Aquamarine worked fine for you, please consider marking their answer as Correct so it can help more people.